# Calculate Percent of Groupby Variable to Sum Column

Tags: pandas, percentage, calculated-columns

I'm not finding a similar example to understand this in python. I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
ID    Capacity
A     50
A     50
A     50
B     30
B     30
B     30
C    100
C    100
C    100
```

I need to find the percent of each ID for the sum of the "Capacity" column. So, the answer looks like this:

```
ID    Capacity   Percent_Capacity
A     50         0.2777
A     50         0.2777
A     50         0.2777
B     30         0.1666
B     30         0.1666
B     30         0.1666
C    100         0.5555
C    100         0.5555
C    100         0.5555
```

Thank you - still learning python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
total=df.groupby('ID')['Capacity'].first().sum()
df['percent_capacity'] = df['Capacity']/total
df
```

```
    ID  Capacity    percent_capacity
0   A         50    0.277778
1   A         50    0.277778
2   A         50    0.277778
3   B         30    0.166667
4   B         30    0.166667
5   B         30    0.166667
6   C        100    0.555556
7   C        100    0.555556
8   C        100    0.555556
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df['percent_capacity'] = df['Capacity']/df.drop_duplicates(subset='ID')['Capacity'].sum()
```

Output:

```
  ID  Capacity  percent_capacity
0  A        50          0.277778
1  A        50          0.277778
2  A        50          0.277778
3  B        30          0.166667
4  B        30          0.166667
5  B        30          0.166667
6  C       100          0.555556
7  C       100          0.555556
8  C       100          0.555556
```